# Finding the most recent indices with different values

Tags: matlab

I am familiar with Matlab but am still having trouble with vectorized methods in my intuition, so I was wondering if anyone could demonstrate how they would manage this problem.

I have an array, for example `A = [1 1 2 2 1 3 3 3 4 3 4 4 5]`.

I want to return an array `B` such that each element is the index of `A`'s most 'recent' element with a different value than the previous ones.

So for our array `A`, `B` would equal `[x x 2 2 4 5 5 5 8 9 10 10 12]`, where the x's can be any consistent value you like, because there is no previous index satisfying those characteristics.

I know how I would code it as a `for`-loop, and I bet the for-loop is probably faster, but can anyone vectorize this to faster than the for-loop?

Here's my `for`-loop:

```
prev=0;  
B=zeros(length(A),1);  
for i=2:length(A)  
  if A(i-1)~=A(i)  
    prev=i-1;  
  end  
  B(i)=prev;  
end
```

Comment: Can you give your `for`-loop implementation please?

Comment: Don't worry about you not getting it based on your intuition. What you described is actually quite difficult to get right with vectorization.

Comment: Finding the index values is simple, `find(diff(A) ~= 0)`, and finding out how often each should be repeated is, too: `l = diff(ind)`. But I don't see how to put these together to form `B` without a loop...

Comment: Ok, got it. `cumsum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the indices of the entries where the value changes:

```
ind = find(diff(A) ~= 0);
```

The values that should appear in `B` are therefore:

```
val = [0 ind];
```

Construct the `diff` of `B`: fill in the difference between the values that should appear at the right places:

```
Bd = zeros(size(B))';
Bd(ind + 1) = diff(val);
```

Now use `cumsum` to construct `B`:

```
B = cumsum(Bd)
```

Not sure whether this results in a speed-up though.

Comment: I timed them both. The for-loop is about ten times slower on an array of 10,000,000 integers(according to matlab's built-in timer). However, when not using the timer, the time required for the command to return is very similar.

Comment: @kision314, interesting. What is the time?

Comment: The matlab timer said ~5.5 seconds for the for-loop, and ~.5 seconds for the vectorized method. Both took about a half-second to return. So maybe the timer functionality slows down the for-loop even more?

Comment: @kision314, sometimes timing is inaccurate if the times are small. Try to put each code into a for-loop that repeats the calculation e.g. 20 times, optimally with different data in each repetition.

Comment: Did that. Control, just producing the random numbers in a loop, takes 5 seconds to run, both by matlab timer and wall-time when I run it normally. The vectorized method takes ~13 seconds to run both by matlab timer and normally. The for-loop takes 106 seconds to run by matlab timer and only ~ 11 seconds normally. How odd.

Comment: Odd indeed. No idea @kision314